# Efficient way to obtain list of ids from sql table that matches list of other ids

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have dynamically created list of ids (int) which I obtain from an external source (thorough webmethod, I stored them in List object at the level of C# code). I have an associate table in SQL database that for each external id stores an internal id. I want to develop a stored procedure to which I put a list of these external ids and retrieve the list of internal ids. There can be a few hundred thousands external ids during each call. I have MS SQL server 2008. Is there an efficient way to do it ?

Comment: You want to develop a stored procedure to do all of this? Then there is no use of C# at all, as far as the question is worded. Why tag it?

Comment: You should probably put that list of id in a temporary table, or a table variable. Please provide sample data and desired results to clarify what you ask for here.

Comment: @AustinTFrench thank you for your remark. I explained in the question why I tagged it as c#.

Comment: Be careful about your choice of temp table. Table variables (e.g., `DECLARE @x TABLE`) have big issues with cardinality estimates and can have bad plans. Real tables (not temp tables) will have their transactions logged, meaning a bit of extra overhead there (you also need to control for concurrency e.g., if you execute it twice at the same time). If you use a temp table, I recommend a Primary Key that matches the Primary Key of the table you are joining to (e.g., `CREATE TABLE #x (id int, PRIMARY KEY(id));`, especially if the data is sorted before inserting it.

Answer (score 1):

You could store your external ID's in a temp table, then join your temp table on the external ID to the External ID in the Internal lookup table and return the results of the internal ID from that join?

If you need code on how to store your id's in a temp table or how to join let me know, but should be able to find the answers to those on stackoverflow as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could import the dynamic list into a temp table (IDs_Temp_T) then run a join:

```
INSERT INTO IDs_Temp_T (ID) VALUES(get_your_ID_Input);

SELECT * 
FROM Table1 INNERJOIN IDs_Temp_T ON Table1.ID = IDs_Temp_T.ID
WHERE TABLE1.ID IS NOT NULL;

DELETE FROM IDs_Temp_T;
```